# Sylius with Symfony 3

Tags: e-commerce, sylius, symfony-3.3

How could I install sylius components in Symfony 3 ?

I'm trying to install SyliusOrderBundle in symfony 3 with composer but always return an error. is there any way to install this component in symfony 3?

Comment: which error? Please describe

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are getting version constraint `^0.18` installed, which is released halfway 2016 and therefore rather old. It's not compatible with the latest Symfony version.

To get the latest version from the `master` branch (warning: this might be unstable): `composer require sylius/order:dev-master`. Normally I wouldn't advice this, but tomorrow version 1.0 of Sylius will be released, so this should be fairly safe today if you upgrade tomorrow to version 1.0.

If you want the lastest beta version that is released: `composer require sylius/order:^1.0.0@dev`. This results in version of some weeks ago, which should be ok to get your project starting with I think.